# Better animation method than requestAnimationFrame for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webgl, emulation, requestanimationframe

Everywhere I see the advice to use requestAnimationFrame. What nobody tells you is that Chrome will throttle to 48 or 30fps based on your power plan, how many tabs you have open, and the phase of the moon, without notifying you in any way. It will do this regardless of the actual work load you’re doing.

For an actual animation, this is fine, if suboptimal. You use the elapsed time to generate a new frame of animation independent of frame rate.

But for something like an emulator it’s unacceptable.

I’m using SharedArrayBuffers, so I’ve already got the annoying headers included with my JavaScript that lets you use a few extra API’s. Is there any alternative to requestAnimationFrame or any way to force it to actually go at least 60Hz?

Comment: I never heard of that throttling and I did study requestAnimationFrame in great deals (to help someone write an academic paper on it). Where have you heard of it? If nobody told you, then show what you did that made you believe they do throttle it. The only throttling I saw in the code was for background tabs, otherwise rAF are mastered by the monitor's VSync signal. My guess is that you are on a G-Sync like monitor, and that your monitor is actually responsible for the frame drops, not the browser.

Comment: Regarding the "for something like an emulator it’s unacceptable.", why? rAF should be used to what goes on screen,  what makes an emulator so special here? If you need a stable clock in tour logic, use a real timer.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no alternative, since the browser's paint job executes as many times as the `requestAnimationFrame` callback is called (when you keep scheduling it at each next call). So if you would do **more** frequent iterations somehow, it wouldn't help, as some of these changes wouldn't make it to the display.

If the issue is about *timing*, then realise that the callback is called with a timestamp, which can help you do realistic calculations. This doesn't change the varying frame rate, but at least allows you to know how much time has passed and base your calculations on that and not on the number of times that the callback is called.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess my question was to;dr because I said that’s the exact point of the timestamp it gives and also why I need 60+fps. So is there any way to deal with the throttling?

Comment: If rAF gives you 30fps there is no way to get 60. The opposite is possible.